# How to explicitly add a cookie in Watir?

Tags: cookies, automation, internet-explorer, watir, ui-automation

I need to set a cookie in IE to execute some specific flow. I tried using the following code

`ieb = Watir::IE.new`

`ieb.document.cookie="rememberme=foobar;Path=/; Domain=sometestdomain.com"`

`# Bring up browser and do bunch of stuff`

However, I see that when the IE comes up, rememberme cookie is not set. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need first open browser with some document loaded from sometestdomain.com.
Then you'll be able to set cookies.

Comment: You may have touched on something possibly affecting my Ruby scripts. I do a browser.new, browser.cookies.add, and then browser.goto "URL pertaining to just-loaded cookies", but those cookies don't seem to take effect and I have to login to a new session on that domain all over.